# Lambda Expression to reverse a string - Java

Tags: java, arrays, lambda, java-8

```
String[] planets = new String[] { "Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", 
                  "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune" };
```

I have a simple array of planet names and I want to reverse each name that was added to the array (not the string order).
I continue to struggle with lambda syntax:

```
Arrays.sort(planets, (first, second) -> new StringBuilder(first).reverse().toString());
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(planets));
```

Currently I get:

> Multiple markers at this line
>
> - The method `reverse()` in the type `StringBuilder` is not applicable for the arguments       `(String)`
> - Type mismatch: cannot convert from `String` to `int`

Response:

Thank you all for suggestions... asList got me close. I still didn't sort correctly.

So i need to find a way to make array.sort work because this was the assignment (to take array.sort and lambda it).

I have pinged the instructor to ask for clarification here, but i am running out of time.

Here is my work attempting to keep array.sort

```
            // lambda expression , long to short
        System.out.println("5) Sorted by length (descending):");
        Arrays.sort(planets, (first, second) -> second.length() - first.length());
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(planets));   

        // lambda expression , reverse the name , then sort in ascending order
        // hint use  new StringBuilder(first).reverse().toString() to reverse the string
        System.out.println("6) Sorted in dictionary order of the reversed name (ascending)");
        Arrays.sort(planets, (first, second) -> new StringBuilder(first).reverse().toString().compareTo(second));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(planets));

        // lambda expression , reverse the name , then sort in descending order
        System.out.println("7) Sorted in dictionary order of the reversed name (descending)");
        Arrays.sort(planets, (first, second) -> new StringBuilder(second).reverse().toString().compareTo(first));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(planets));
```

What I cannot for the life of me figure out here is that all 3 expressions get me exactly the same result... each of those gives me the original array sorted longest to shortest.

This is my result:

5) Sorted by length (descending):
[Neptune, Mercury, Jupiter, Uranus, Saturn, Venus, Earth, Mars]

6) Sorted in dictionary order of the reversed name (ascending)
[Neptune, Mercury, Jupiter, Uranus, Saturn, Venus, Earth, Mars]

7) Sorted in dictionary order of the reversed name (descending)
[Neptune, Mercury, Jupiter, Uranus, Saturn, Venus, Earth, Mars]

Comment: Why are you calling `Arrays.sort()`?

Comment: I am using Arrays.sort() because I was asked to for a homework assignment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An alternative solution which does not use Stream API and updates the strings in-place:

```
Arrays.asList(planets).replaceAll(s -> new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString());
```

Demo:

```
String[] planets = new String[] { "Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", 
        "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune" };
Arrays.asList(planets).replaceAll(s -> new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString());
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(planets));
// [yrucreM, suneV, htraE, sraM, retipuJ, nrutaS, sunarU, enutpeN]
```

Comment: `replaceAll()`.. Hmm interesting approach.. +1 :)

Answer (score 4):

This will do it for you :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] arr = {"earth", "mars", "mercury"};
    List<String> ll = Arrays.stream(arr).map(s -> new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(ll);
}
```

O/P :

```
[htrae, sram, yrucrem]
```

Or if you just want to print, use this :

```
String[] arr = {"earth", "mars", "mercury"};
Arrays.stream(arr).map(s -> new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

O/P :

```
htrae
sram
yrucrem
```

Comment: If you’re going to print the results directly with a chained `forEach`, you may omit the `.toString()` call…

Answer (score 2):

`Arrays.sort` requires a comparator as a second argument. It can be implemented with a lambda expression that takes two strings as parameters (in your case) and return an integer (this is the requirement of the SAM defined in the `Comparator` interface).

```
(first, second) -> new StringBuilder(first).reverse().toString()
```

is a lambda expression that takes two strings (the type is inferred by the compiler), but it returns a string and not an integer, hence the error:

```
java: incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) T
    (argument mismatch; bad return type in lambda expression
      java.lang.String cannot be converted to int)
```

> I have a simple array of planet names and I want to reverse each name
>   that was added to the array

In this case you can simply use `Arrays.setAll` to modify the array in place:

```
Arrays.setAll(planets, i -> new StringBuilder(planets[i]).reverse().toString());
```

Comment: So here is my code: Arrays.setAll(planets, i -> new StringBuilder(planets[i]).reverse().toString()); but i get the following trying this: The method setAll(String[], (<no type> i) -> {}) is undefined for the type Arrays

Answer (score 0):

```
// Sort and reverse
String[] planetsOne = new String[] { "Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", 
        "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune" };
  String temp [ ] = Arrays.stream(planetsOne).sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()).toArray(String[ ] ::new);
      for(String node : planetsOne) {
      System.out.print("     "+ node);
      }
      
      System.out.println("\n ");
      
      // only reverse does not sort
    String[] planetsTwo
    = new String[] { "Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", 
            "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune" };
    
      Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(planetsTwo));
      for(String node : planetsTwo) {
      System.out.print("     "+ node);
      }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).